# C++ Runtime Initialization

Tags: c++, arm

I'm programming on ARM platform. When I want use C, I must compile my code with a ctr0.o to execute C runtime initialization.

But I want to use C++ against C, and I don't know the equivalent of ctr0.o to initilize C++ code

Can you help me ?
Ty

Comment: There should be the correct one linked if you use g++.

Comment: Really depends on the compiler toolchain you're using and by your target environment (bare-metal, RTOS, linux,...).